# TxTranslation WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I wanna use this library to localize my application. I really like their tool to edit files and It looks like it esy to use. I've created tsd file and It looks right but It doesn't work inside app.

[My txd file to localize application](http://www.filedropper.com/translations)

The version of library

```
    `<package id="Unclassified.TxLib" version="1.184.37" targetFramework="net45" />`

xmlns:Tx="http://unclassified.software/source/txtranslation"
```

.......

```
<TextBlock
            x:Uid="HomePage_Title"
            Name="txtTitle"
            Foreground="White"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            FontSize="32"
            Padding="30"
            Text="{Tx:UT Key=homepage.title}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: You don't need both `Tx.LoadDirectory` and `Tx.LoadFromXmlFile`, one is enough. But it doesn't hurt. The rest looks okay. But I've never tried to write `{Tx:T Key=myKey}` but instead only `{Tx:T myKey}`. Have you tried that? And what does it show at that place? Nothing (which is unusual) or the text key in brackets: `[homepage.title]` (which means that the keys was not found)? Also, the resolution is only done at runtime, never at design time inside Visual Studio because the dictionary loading code isn't run there.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about LoadDirectory is enough. What version of Tx do you use? I'm using TxTranslation 1.383.76. I can't use key without 'Key' work. It's an error that there's a constructor.

Comment: The Key/non-Key has never been changed since it's been initially written. I never use the Key property explicitly, only use the one-string constructor parameter. Any version works for me. VS 2010, 2013 and 2015.

Comment: Your dictionary file looks weird. The key "homepage.title" does not exist. Instead there are lots of keys like "UT ..." inside the Tx-internal namespace. Please compare your file with the one that TxEditor uses itself, and don't edit the XML file manually but use TxEditor for that. But even if I create the missing key in your file, your code doesn't work yet. I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. You just shouldn't set the text foreground colour to white on a white background. ;-)

And you should review your dictionary. The text keys look weird. See my comment above.

Comment: Could you tell me please? Why UT extension doesn't work? I have a button with content <Button Content="{Tx:UT Key=Tx:homepage.button.code}" />. It should convert text to uppercase but It doesn't do that. Everything else works perfect.

Comment: Please provide further information about your new situation. Last time I checked, it did work.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Everything works fine except this. I can use several extensions, I mean {Tx:T} - just text; {Tx:UT} - uppercase etc. But I always get the exact text I wrote in the txd file.

Comment: What is the expected result and what the actual? Please provide real data for this. I cannot reproduce it at all.

Comment: I've attached the last translation file with xml and the version of library I use is **1.184.37**. If you see uppercase string in the file that's mean I can't convert this string using UT attribute. Thanks for help and sorry If I'm not specific in my question.

Comment: You need to grant me access on a file you want me to download.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the file accidentally. Now I moved it to FileDropper. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Please do not put your keys all under the "Tx:" system namespace. It's not made for that. You may get unexpected behaviour. Please look at the dictionary file of TxEditor itself to learn about it. Also, `UT` does not uppercase the entire string but only the first character. This is meant to use texts both within a sentence and as the start of a sentence. Uppercasing an entire string is a decoration thing that should be handled with text transformations and other features on the presentation level.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there's no extension in Tx library in order to convert whole string to the upper case string but this is true. I have created this extension by myself. Here's the code may be it'll help somebody.

```
/// <summary>
/// Markup extension providing the Tx.UT method functionality.
/// </summary>
public class UATExtension : TExtension
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the UATExtension class.
    /// </summary>
    public UATExtension()
        : base()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the UATExtension class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Text key to translate.</param>
    public UATExtension(string key)
        : base(key)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the UATExtension class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Text key to translate.</param>
    /// <param name="count">Count value to consider when selecting the text value.</param>
    public UATExtension(string key, int count)
        : base(key, count)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the UATExtension class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Text key to translate.</param>
    /// <param name="countBinding">Binding that provides the count value to consider when selecting the text value.</param>
    public UATExtension(string key, Binding countBinding)
        : base(key, countBinding)
    {
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Converter action

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the T method in specialised classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Func<string, int, string> GetTFunc()
    {
        return TTx.UAT;
    }

    #endregion Converter action
}
```

And inside of the extension I'm using my own class TxService where I have just added all the same methods which there're in the original Tx class for UT abbreviation.

```
public static class TxService
{


    #region UAT overloads

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, int count)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, count));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, decimal count)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, count));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, params string[] data)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, data));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, data));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, int count, params string[] data)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, count, data));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, int count, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, count, data));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, decimal count, params string[] data)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, count, data));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combined abbreviation for the UpperCase and Text methods.
    /// </summary>
    public static string UAT(string key, decimal count, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        return UA(Tx.T(key, count, data));
    }

    #endregion UT overloads

    /// <summary>
    /// Abbreviation for the <see cref="UpperCaseAll"/> method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string UA(string text)
    {
        return UpperCaseAll(text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transforms the first character of a text to upper case.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Text to transform.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string UpperCaseAll(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return text;
        return text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```